# Add more than 256 ip adresses on the same network

Tags: networking, router

I'm trying to include more than 256 devices in one network, so I made some changes:

- Router 1:

This is the ISP provider Router

```
   LAN IP  : 190.168.1.1
   DHCP    : 190.168.1.10 - 190.168.1.250
   MASK    : 255.255.0.0    
   Gateway : 190.168.1.1
```

- Router 2:

This is the router I want to use for my devices:

```
LAN IP  : 190.168.1.2
DHCP    : 190.168.2.10 - 190.168.2.250
MASK    : 255.255.0.0
Gateway : 190.168.1.1
```

- Router (3...10):

This is the router I want to use for my **clients**:

```
LAN IP : 190.168.1.(3...10)
DHCP   : 190.168.(3...10).10 - 190.168.(3...10).250
MASK   : 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 190.168.1.1
```

Why isn't this working as one ?

Comment: Your setup (which will work with `/24` network masks) does not result in the devices being on one network.

Comment: I hope `190` is the typo you made only here by the way.

Comment: @DanielB why is it a /24 ? I was trying to be on the /16 network mask and put it all on the same network

Comment: @TomYan I was hopping that with this ip address I would get a Class B network

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Answer (score 0):

So, this sould work:

- Router 1:

ISP provider Router

```
   LAN IP  : 10.0.0.1
   DHCP    : 190.168.1.10 - 190.168.1.250
   MASK    : 255.0.0.0  
   Gateway : 10.0.0.1
```

- Router 2:

Personal devices:

```
LAN IP  : 10.0.0.2
DHCP    : 10.0.1.10 - 10.0.1.250
MASK    : 255.0.0.0
Gateway : 10.0.0.1
```

- Router (3...10):

Clients devices

```
LAN IP : 10.0.0.(3...10)
DHCP   : 10.0.(3...10).10 - 10.0.(3...10).250
MASK   : 255.0.0.0
Gateway: 10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all: Classful networking is dead and has been for a rather long time. Just forget about it. Make sure you stick to private address ranges or you risk breakage when address conflicts arise. **`190.168.x.x` is *not* a private address range.**

“One network” kind of implies that all devices are on the same broadcast domain. That means no additional routers. No isolation either. Is that really what you want? From your description this doesn’t appear to be the case. Either way, just set an appropriate network mask (like `/16`) and DHCP range on the one router and you’re done.

It appears you actually want separate networks that may or may not be able to communicate with each other. This is easily accomplished by using non-NAT routing and appropriate routes on *all* routers involved. Routers can also firewall traffic as required. The networks (as defined by the network address and network mask) *must not* overlap. The broadcast domains must be fully separated by routers, otherwise you’ll get conflicts with multiple DHCP servers on one network.